# Power Shell Find Duplicate Values and modify them

Tags: powershell, csv, for-loop, parsing

Have a script that parses csv file but it does not work as needed
Here is some content from csv file

```
id,location_id,name,title,email,department
1,1,Susan houston,Director of Services,,
2,1,Christina Gonzalez,Director,,
3,2,Brenda brown,"Director, Second Career Services",,
4,3,Howard Lader,"Manager, Senior Counseling",,
5,4,Kimberly Pesavento,Commercial director,,
6,5,Joe Bloom,Financial Empowerment Programs Program Director,,
7,6,peter Olson,Director,,
8,6,Bart charlow,Executive Director,,
9,7,Bart Charlow,Executive Director,,
```

```
Param 
( 
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)] 
    [string]$filePath 
) 
$inputFile = Import-Csv -Path $filePath
$text = (Get-Culture).TextInfo
$HashSet = [System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]]::new([System.StringComparer]::OrdinalIgnoreCase)

foreach ($line in $inputFile) {
    $name = $line.name
    $line.name = $text.ToTitleCase($name)
    $firstName = $line.name.split(" ")[0]
    $lastName = $line.name.split(" ")[1]
    $newEmail = ($firstName[0] + $lastName).toLower()

    if (!$HashSet.Add($newEmail)) {
        $line.email = ($firstName[0] + $lastName + $line.location_id + "@abc.com").toLower()
    }
    else {
        $line.email = ($firstName[0] + $lastName + "@abc.com").toLower()
    }
} 

$inputFile | Export-Csv -UseQuotes AsNeeded ./accounts_new.csv
```

here is the output of the script

```
"id","location_id","name","title","email","department"
"1","1","Susan Houston","Director of Services","shouston@abc.com",""
"2","1","Christina Gonzalez","Director","cgonzalez@abc.com",""
"3","2","Brenda Brown","Director, Second Career Services","bbrown@abc.com",""
"4","3","Howard Lader","Manager, Senior Counseling","hlader@abc.com",""
"5","4","Kimberly Pesavento","Commercial director","kpesavento@abc.com",""
"6","5","Joe Bloom","Financial Empowerment Programs Program Director","jbloom@abc.com",""
"7","6","Peter Olson","Director","polson@abc.com",""
"8","6","Bart Charlow","Executive Director","bcharlow@abc.com",""
"9","7","Bart Charlow","Executive Director","bcharlow7@abc.com",""
```

As you can see from last 2 rows location_id is appended only the second equal email but the first one remains untouched, how can I add location_id to the first one also?

Can you help me? Thanks!

I tried to use while instead of if statement but it didn't help me

Comment: The real question is: why are you programming *anything* to parse CSV files in the first place?

Comment: It is for home task, thanks!

Comment: Not sure if this is the correct site for this, this is requiring a bit more help than just pointing out a single error. Don't you have an assistant that can help you out? Currently you're not even skipping the first line or splitting at the comma. I don't see you using functions either, which is really important when starting to program.

Comment: I'm not really clear on what the *expected* output is for your sample data - could you show that as well as the current output?

Comment: I agree with mclayton, it's not clear if the guy on id `8` should be `bcharlow6@abc.com` or `bcharlow7@abc.com`

Comment: Thank you, the expected output is "8","6","Bart Charlow","Executive Director","bcharlow6@abc.com",""
"9","7","Bart Charlow","Executive Director","bcharlow7@abc.com",""

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I see around this would be to group the CSV by the `name` property and then use the `location_id` if there are 2 or more objects with the same `name` value. For this you can use [`Group-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object?view=powershell-7.3).

```bash
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
    [string] $FilePath
)

$re  = '(?<=^[a-z]{1})\S*\s'
$txt = (Get-Culture).TextInfo
$csv = Import-Csv -Path $filePath
$map = $csv | Group-Object { $_.name -replace $re } -AsHashTable -AsString

$csv | ForEach-Object {
    $_.name = $txt.ToTitleCase($_.name)
    $userName = $_.name -replace $re
    # if there is only one user with the same constructed user name
    if($map[$userName].Count -eq 1) {
        # use their Name and Last Name only
        $_.email = $userName.ToLower() + "@abc.com"
        return $_
    }

    # else, use also their Location_Id
    $_.email = $userName.ToLower() + $_.location_id + "@abc.com"
    $_
} | Export-Csv -UseQuotes AsNeeded ./accounts_new.csv
```

Output using the example Csv in the question would become:

```
id location_id name               title                                           email              department
-- ----------- ----               -----                                           -----              ----------
1  1           Susan Houston      Director of Services                            shouston@abc.com
2  1           Christina Gonzalez Director                                        cgonzalez@abc.com
3  2           Brenda Brown       Director, Second Career Services                bbrown@abc.com
4  3           Howard Lader       Manager, Senior Counseling                      hlader@abc.com
5  4           Kimberly Pesavento Commercial director                             kpesavento@abc.com
6  5           Joe Bloom          Financial Empowerment Programs Program Director jbloom@abc.com
7  6           Peter Olson        Director                                        polson@abc.com
8  6           Bart Charlow       Executive Director                              bcharlow6@abc.com
9  7           Bart Charlow       Executive Director                              bcharlow7@abc.com
```

Comment: @NarekArakelyan mm see update, that might work

Comment: @NarekArakelyan actually using this regex method, the function might not be needed at all

Comment: That seems to work as well, again thanks for your help!

Comment: @NarekArakelyan happy it was helpful :)

Comment: Is there a bash version of the same task? I have another question with the same task but only bash? Thanks

Comment: @NarekArakelyan I'm sorry I dont know bash, only PowerShell and a bit of C#